# `AnnotationConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext` has not been refreshed yet

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, websphere-8

Installing a SpringBoot Legacy (web.xml) WAR application with filters (DelegatingFilterProxy), I was given the following error/stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.AnnotationConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@fff88888 has not been refreshed yet

#### The supplied logs...

```
[ERROR] 2016-01-11 11:11:11,265 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.AnnotationConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@fff88888 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1041)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1059)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initMultipartResolver(DispatcherServlet.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:471)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:559)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.load(ServletWrapper.java:1375)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1024)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3815)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:518)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:309)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:280)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1720)
[ERROR] 2016-01-11 11:11:11,266 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper - Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[ERROR] 2016-01-11 11:11:11,267 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp - SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[appServlet]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.AnnotationConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@fff88888 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1041)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1059)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:604)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3815)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:518)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:309)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:280)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1720)
```

#### Applications versions:

- **Websphere Application Server:** 8.0.0.10
- **SpringBoot:** 1.3.3.RELEASE

#### Similar issues (their fixes were unrelated):

- [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has not been refreshed yet - what's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404817/annotationconfigapplicationcontext-has-not-been-refreshed-yet-whats-wrong)
- [Spring 4 upgrade now junit tests fails on "GenericApplicationContext has not been refreshed yet"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108928/spring-4-upgrade-now-junit-tests-fails-on-genericapplicationcontext-has-not-bee)
- [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has not been refreshed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842512/annotationconfigapplicationcontext-has-not-been-refreshed-yet)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry to do the question+answer thing. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else...

Looking at (only) the stacktrace provided, it looks like the issue occurred when the `DelegatingFilterProxy` asserted if the `BeanFactory` was active (this is a good start, sounded like the application context had an issue initialising...).

Upon getting access to the FULL logs, I found out the application context had failed much earlier on (issue with creating a bean - a missing file), and that this message was just the "ripples" from that original issue.

Moral of the story (**tl;dr**):

- this stacktrace is a symptom, look for the root cause (& check the full logs)